# how to create an Cloud Recognition Application in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I tried the example which is shown in below link:
http://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Implement-Cloud-Recognition-using-the-Native-SDKs As per the unity tutorial for Cloud Recognition is not Showing up the 3D model.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an empty project and extract the latest Vuforia plugin into the project. https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk
2. Download a sample Vuforia project (Core features)
   https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples
3. Create your licence key and set target on Vuforia for cloud.
4. Open the cloud reco sample project from SampleScene.
5. Copy the licence key from Vuforia Licence Manager and paste it into Vuforia Configuration Licence key.
6. Copy your access key and secret key from target manager and paste it into Cloud recognition prefab and play.